# Derive $\vec F = P \vec A$ using BBGKY hierarchy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

So I've been reading this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/681142/150174).

> The question boils down to how we calculate pressure on microscopic
> level in absence of a rigid boundary. In statistical physics pressure
> by a gas on a boundary is calculated from the change of momentum of
> atoms/molecules reflected by the boundary. In absence of a boundary
> one could suggest scattering against other molecules - but then, what
> is the difference between mascroscopic (bouyancy, convection)
> microscopic (diffusion, heat conduction) behavior of a gas?

It seems to me that one can start from [BBGKY hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBGKY_hierarchy#:%7E:text=In%20statistical%20physics%2C%20the%20BBGKY%20hierarchy%20%28%20Bogoliubov%E2%80%93Born%E2%80%93Green%E2%80%93Kirkwood%E2%80%93Yvon,system%20of%20a%20large%20number%20of%20interacting%20particles.) and derive all properties pertaining to a gas?

How does one derive that the equation of motion in the continuum limit should be:

$$ \vec F = P \vec A$$

starting from BBGKY hierarchy?

Comment: I think, $\vec F = P\vec A$ is itself the definition of pressure. How can you derive it from any other theory?

Comment: @SCh I can define anything but then the question becomes why should my theory respect this definition. BBGKY hierarchy starts of from kinetic theory and aims to do this.

Comment: I tend to agree, we would probably view F=PA as the definition of P. We then have to show that other definitions, for example P=dS/dV_{E,N} (thermodynamics), P=-T/V log Z (stat mech),  P\delta_{ij}=T_{ij} (GR) are equivalent to it. This is discussed in various text books, but I don't quite see how it is related to BBGKY

Comment: @thomas there are 2 ways to derive Euler's equations. 1. From using BBGKY hierarchy and 2. From using $F=PA$. I don't think then it's a stretch to think BBGKY can also derive it?

Comment: Well, if BBGKY implies Euler, and Euler implies F=PA, then BBGKY implies F=PA, right?

Comment: No $F=PA$ implies Euler not sure about the other way round.

Comment: Seems pretty clear, just apply F=ma to a volume element with a free surface. But again, I don't think that BBGKY has anything to do with this. What is doing the "heavy lifting" here is the equivalence of different definitions of P.

Comment: Would you recommend I rephrase the question and ask for this equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

According to your link $\mathbf{F}_{i}=-\frac{\partial \Phi_{i}^{ext}}{\partial q_{i}}$

the interaction potential $\Phi_{i,j} $ is assumed to be zero.

we know that: $F=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial r}\;\;\;(1)$

taking the average over this equality, we find: $\bar{F}=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}dS\;\;\;\;(2)$

so $\;\;P=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\;\;\;\;(3)$, Pascal's law
and: $F=PdS $

(1),(2),(3) L.Landau, E.Lifchitz statistical physics first part,volume V.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty but I am still dissatisfied, Because 1. This assumes the collision duration to be $0$. 2. Usually I would have to dot product $F$ with $dS$. I see no $\cos \theta$. $\bar F = \int F \cdot dS / dS = F \cos \theta$ (using Rolle's theorem)

Comment: "We average over a set that satisfies the instantaneous external constraints", see page 108,109 https://www.physique.usherbrooke.ca/tremblay/cours/PHQ-340/stat-340.pdf,